# Dropping different possible combination of values from a column in pandas dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd 
Data = pd.DataFrame({'L1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'L2': [6,7,3,5,6], 'ouptput':[10,11,12,13,14]})
Data
```

Yields,

```
    L1  L2  ouptput
0   1   6   10
1   2   7   11
2   3   3   12
3   4   5   13
4   5   6   14
```

I want to loop through the data to remove n number of values from the column 'output' in above Data, where n = [1,2,3,4] and assign it to a new data frame 'Test_Data'. For example if I assign n = 2 the function should produce

Test_Data - iteration 1  as

```
       L1   L2  ouptput
    0   1   6   
    1   2   7   
    2   3   3   12
    3   4   5   13
    4   5   6   14
```

Test_Data - iteration 2  as

```
       L1   L2  ouptput
    0   1   6   10
    1   2   7   11
    2   3   3   
    3   4   5   
    4   5   6   14
```

like wise it should produce a data frame with 2 values removed from the 'output' column in data frame. It should produce a new output (new combination) everytime. No output should be repeated. Also I should have control over the number of iterations. Eample 5c3 has 10 possible combinations. But I should be able to stop it at 8 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great solution but will probably help you achieve what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd 
Data = pd.DataFrame({'L1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'L2': [6,7,3,5,6], 'output':[10,11,12,13,14]})
num_iterations = 1
num_values = 3
for i in range(0, num_iterations):
    tmp_data = Data.copy()
    tmp_data.loc[i*num_values:num_values*(i+1)-1, 'output'] = ''
    print tmp_data
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a concatenated dataframe with every combination using `pd.concat` and `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

def mask(df, col, idx):
    d = df.copy()
    d.loc[list(idx), col] = ''
    return d

n = 2
pd.concat({c: mask(Data, 'ouptput', c) for c in combinations(Data.index, n)})

       L1  L2 ouptput
0 1 0   1   6        
    1   2   7        
    2   3   3      12
    3   4   5      13
    4   5   6      14
  2 0   1   6        
    1   2   7      11
    2   3   3        
    3   4   5      13
    4   5   6      14
  3 0   1   6        
    1   2   7      11
    2   3   3      12
    3   4   5        
    4   5   6      14
  4 0   1   6        
    1   2   7      11
    2   3   3      12
    3   4   5      13
    4   5   6        
1 2 0   1   6      10
    1   2   7        
    2   3   3        
    3   4   5      13
    4   5   6      14
  3 0   1   6      10
    1   2   7        
    2   3   3      12
    3   4   5        
    4   5   6      14
  4 0   1   6      10
    1   2   7        
    2   3   3      12
    3   4   5      13
    4   5   6        
2 3 0   1   6      10
    1   2   7      11
    2   3   3        
    3   4   5        
    4   5   6      14
  4 0   1   6      10
    1   2   7      11
    2   3   3        
    3   4   5      13
    4   5   6        
3 4 0   1   6      10
    1   2   7      11
    2   3   3      12
    3   4   5        
    4   5   6
```